# Can @Configuration work without @componentScan (Spring JavaConfig @annotaion)

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-java-config

--Appconfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {    

  @Bean(name="helloBean")
  public HelloWorld helloWorld() {
    return new HelloWorldImpl();
   }
}
```

--interface.java

```
public interface HelloWorld {
    void printHelloWorld(String msg);
}
```

--ipml.java

```
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {
public void printHelloWorld(String msg) {
    System.out.println("Hello! : " + msg);
   --
}
```

--App.java

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new 
    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean(HelloWorldImpl.class);

obj.printHelloWorld("Spring3 Java Config");
   }
}
```

My program can works, but my question is why I don't need to add `@componentScan` in Appconfig.java .

It seems to `@Configuration` and `@Bean` can be found by Spring whithout using `@componentScan`.

I thought if you want to use @annotation ,you must use @componentScan or

`context:component-scan(xml)`, 
am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@ComponentScan` allows spring to auto scan all your components with `@Component` annotated. Spring uses the base-package attribute, which indicates where to find components.

`@Configuration` is meta annotated with `@Component`, which marks it eligible for classpath scanning.

`@Configuration` (AppConfig class) is registered when you use

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

`@Bean` doesn't need `@ComponentScan` as all these beans are created explicitly when spring encounters this annotation.